# file_field doesn't appear in browser

Tags: filefield

I'm using the file_field to upload a photo, I've installed gem 'carrierwave' and in the edit view from a user i have this:

```
<h1>Actualizar</h1>
<div>
<%= form_for current_user, :html => { :multipart => true }  do |x| %>
<label>Introduzca su nombre:</label>
<%= x.text_field :name %>
<br>
<!--<label>Introduzca su contraseña:</label>
<%= x.password_field :password %>
<br>-->
<label>Introduzca su username:</label>
<%= x.text_field :username %>
<br>
<label>Introduzca su email:</label>
<%= x.text_field :email %>
<br>
<div>
<label>Selecione imagen:</label>
<%= x.file_field :file %>
</div>
<br>
<%= x.submit "Aceptar"%>
<%end%>
</div>
```

When i open the browser the file_field doesn't appear.